# Would a pair of independent quantum coin tosses be perfectly anti-correlated?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, measurement-problem

### Background

Suppose we attach a button to an electronic flip flop such that an LED will toggle when we press the button with 50% probability, where the source of the randomness is a quantum event, such as using a Geiger counter to detect whether the next detected arrival was at an even or odd number of milliseconds (I don't think the details really matter).

We assume the LED is off initially.

If we press the button once, then it is clear that the LED will be on with probability 50%. (Illustrated as experiment 1.  Each column represents a different experimental run.)

If we look and then press the button again, the LED may or may not change to a different state.

### Question

What happens if we press the button twice (without peeking in the middle)? (Illustrated in experiment 2.)

### My thoughts

Intuitively it feels that this should just make the outputs different, but just as randomly distributed as after one button press.

My problem arises when I consider this from a Quantum mechanics framework.
My understanding is that the action of pressing a button can be represented as a Unitary matrix acting on the amplitudes of the different possible states.

Initially we are certainly in state 0, and after a single button press we are 50% in state 0, and 50% in state 1.  Therefore this feels like a rotation of 45 degrees.

But, if this is correct, then when I press the button twice I end up with a total rotation of 90 degrees and therefore we are certainly in state 1!

Of course, in practice the apparatus is not sufficiently shielded and the system will behave classically - but I am interested in whether this logic is theoretically flawed rather than practical reasons why I can't test this with a real experiment.

### Request

Can anyone help me understand this contradiction?  (By the way, this is not a homework question - just something that I was discussing with my son as a thought experiment after reading Quarantine by Greg Egan - highly recommended.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter whether or not you look. What matters is that it is possible to look *in principle*, because the quantum particle interacts with the LED and therefore becomes entangled with it (your unitary matrix acts on *both* the particle and LED). So the outcome will always be the same as experiment 1. The technical term for this is "which-way" information: the state of the LED contains the information about whether or not the particle decayed. As long as which-way information is available in principle, it does not matter whether or not you choose to make use of this information.

You can see why this must be so: imagine that you choose not to look, but your son does choose to look at the LED at time 1. It must be the case that you both see the same physical outcome when you both look at time 2.

Comment: My thought was that after pressing the button twice, the which-way information has been lost.  The idea is that the experiment should be set up such that there is no way of telling afterwards whether the LED toggled on the first button press, or the second.  All that is known is whether there were an even or odd total number of toggles. Does this change things?

Comment: How about if the actual visible output was disabled during the experiment (either by placing the apparatus in a box, or simply not connecting the LEDs until after the buttons have been pressed).

Comment: The which-way information is not lost if the state of the LED can be affected by whether or not the particle decays. Rather, the which-way information is leaked to the environment as photons. This process is effectively irreversible, so it is totally impractical to capture the leaked photons since they fly away at the speed of light. However, *in principle* the information is stored in the state of the radiation field and some other observer could use it.

Comment: About your second comment, I am not sure exactly what setup you have in mind. The point is simply this: if the quantum particle or decay event interacts with some ancillary system (e.g. LED), so that the state of the ancillary system is conditioned on whether or not the particle decayed, then the situation will be as in experiment 1. This is because experiment 2 requires the quantum particle to remain locally phase coherent. However if it interacts with and becomes entangled with another system this local coherence is lost.

Comment: I think I see.  So if I had a system where I had a single well isolated quantum particle that had exactly a 50% chance of toggling state in 1 second (and it starts in state 0), then if I observe after 1 second I would see random results, but if I observe after 2 seconds then I would always see state 1.  However, my setup with electronics and LEDs is far too large a system and therefore the wavefunction would always effectively have collapsed way before the observation at time 2. Is this right?

Comment: If you have a smooth unitary evolution of an isolated particle that takes you between 0 and 1 at constant "speed" over 2 seconds, then your first assertion is correct. However, the problem with interacting with another system is nothing to do with size. Even if you replaced the LED with a single photon or electron, as long as the state of this second particle becomes conditioned on the state of the first one, the oscillatory dynamics between 0 and 1 of the first particle disappears. This is called "decoherence". "Collapse" is just a philosophical idea that is not necessary to explain physics.

Comment: I am afraid there is not really a better or intuitive way to help you understand this unless you want to become proficient in quantum mechanics to undergraduate level. It is just a fact that when two quantum mechanical systems become correlated, individually these systems lose their quantum mechanical character and start to behave classically. Globally they still behave quantum mechanically but you have to look at the correlations to see it. If you just look at what happens to one system (e.g. looking just at the LED) it behaves just like a classical random bit.